# cannot see color on progress bar using twitter bootstrap 3 in a rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, colors, progress-bar, less

In a view index.html.erb file

I have the following in a table

```
  <td><div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="#{number_to_percentage(u.percentage_complete, :precision => 2)}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
     <span class="sr-only"><%= number_to_percentage(u.percentage_complete, :precision => 2)%></span>
    </div>
   </div>
 </td>
```

Problem is I cannot see any color in the progress bar that generated as a result of this code:

See this there is a shadow outline under "percentage completed" but no color(Sorry its barely visible if you look closely). How do I fix this. I presume I have to do something in the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file?

Any help would be greatly apreciated. 
[image]

---

UPDATE

I changed my code to this:

```
   <td><div class="progress progress-striped">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"   role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="#{number_to_percentage(u.percentage_complete, :precision => 2)}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%; background-color:green">
   <span class="sr-only"><%= number_to_percentage(u.percentage_complete, :precision => 0)%>
  </span>
   </div>
```

I added style background color above and changed the width to 100%. This changed the rendering as below:

[image]

but I am trying to do this in LESS and based on [this](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) website I tried to update my bootstrap_and_overrides file to look like this:

```
 //@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
 //@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/reset.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/variables.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/mixins.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/scaffolding.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/grid.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/layouts.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/type.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/forms.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/wells.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/component-animations.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/buttons.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/close.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/navs.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/navbar.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/labels-badges.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/hero-unit.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/utilities.less";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";


 // Set the correct sprite paths
 @iconSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
 @iconWhiteSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");

 // Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
 @fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
 @fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
 @fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
 @fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
 @fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

 // Font Awesome
 @import "fontawesome/font-awesome";

 // Glyphicons
 //@import "twitter/bootstrap/sprites.less";

 // Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
 //
 // Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
 // you may use and inherit here
 //
 // If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
 // See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
 //
 // Example:
 // @linkColor: #ff0000;


 @progress-bg: #000000
```

I then restarted the server and tried to load the page to see the progress bar. This time the page doesn't load and I see an error which "Unrecognized input" coming from this line:

```
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

in my application.html.erb file

Comment: can you make sure that you are loading all the CSS files? and the assets are being compiled properly

Comment: Please look at my update above

Comment: Are all those @import compiling and showing up in your HTML when you view source

Comment: `@progress-bg: #000000` should end with a `;`? `@progress-bg: #000000;`

Comment: is there a good reference/book/tutorial where I can learn about LESS and this preprocessor stuff with bootstrap? Thx

Comment: - That semicolon prevented the error but I still cannot get the colors on the progress bar:(

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap_and_overrides you do **NOT** import progress-bars.less. Check: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less for a complete list of Bootstrap's LESS files.

When wrapping your progress bars into tables make sure give your table a width. Set to 100% for example. The easiest way to do this will be by adding class `table` to your table.

```
<table class="table">
```

See also: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://bootply.com/106949